# SQL distinct com sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, distinct

Olá, estou com um problema em fazer uma soma em uma query.
Exemplo e resultados da query:

```
select DISTINCT t.ID, t.nomeuc as "Nome UC", 
    t.tipoturno as "Tipo Turno", a.num_presencas as "Número de Presenças"
from ei_sad_proj_gisem.v_aulas_semana a 
    join ei_sad_proj_gisem.v_turnos t on a.turno_ID = t.ID
where turno_ID in (
    select ID 
    from ei_sad_proj_gisem.v_turnos 
    where abrevuc = 'SAD' group by ID);
```

E tenho um output de:

> ```
>    ID Nome UC                                            Tipo  Número de Presenças
> ```
>
> ---

```
   171 Sistemas de Apoio à Decisão                        PL                     13
   149 Sistemas de Apoio à Decisão                        PL                     16
   146 Sistemas de Apoio à Decisão                        PL                     17
   148 Sistemas de Apoio à Decisão                        PL                     14
   151 Sistemas de Apoio à Decisão                        T                      53
   171 Sistemas de Apoio à Decisão                        PL                     14
   151 Sistemas de Apoio à Decisão                        T                      46
   148 Sistemas de Apoio à Decisão                        PL                     16

30 rows selected.
```

Eu quero somar a quantidade de presenças, no entanto quando adiciono apenas o SUM() tenho um erro de **ORA-00937: não é uma função de grupo de grupo-único**

O código seria o seguinte:

```
select DISTINCT t.ID, t.nomeuc as "Nome UC", 
    t.tipoturno as "Tipo Turno", SUM(a.num_presencas) as "Número de Presenças"
from ei_sad_proj_gisem.v_aulas_semana a 
    join ei_sad_proj_gisem.v_turnos t on a.turno_ID = t.ID
where turno_ID in (
    select ID 
    from ei_sad_proj_gisem.v_turnos 
    where abrevuc = 'SAD' group by ID);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acho que só falta o group by na primeira query, e você não pode usar o ID, claro, se não, não vai agregar

```
select 
t.nomeuc as "Nome UC", 
t.tipoturno as "Tipo Turno", 
SUM(a.num_presencas) as "Número de Presenças"
from ei_sad_proj_gisem.v_aulas_semana a 
join ei_sad_proj_gisem.v_turnos t on a.turno_ID = t.ID
where turno_ID in (
    select ID 
    from ei_sad_proj_gisem.v_turnos 
    where abrevuc = 'SAD' group by ID)
group by t.ID, t.nomeuc, t.tipoturno;
```

Comment: removi @JeffersonQuesado, removi também a ID que não deixaria agregar

Comment: Obrigado @Rovann! Irei marcar como resposta quando passar os 10 mins!